# Codeigniter keeps creating new session IDs which ultimately destroys any and all userdata

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

This was my original configuration:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

and after my website kept clearing userdata after an unknown amount of time [like a couple minutes] (via creating new session id and inserting a new row in mysql) for reasons unknown, I decided maybe it was because CI was trying to match the useragent, but was doing so unsuccessfully so it would create a new session and effectively clear any and all userdata and starting over (but what I do not understand is the fact that I'm using the same browser, chrome, and if this is in fact the problem then either chrome keeps changing its useragent headers or whatever, or CI has a bug...)
anyways, now i changed it to:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

I hope this fixes the problem...
If not, what would cause the problem?

Comment: Check if your user_agent field in database is long enough.

Comment: @YellowBird The thing is, wouldn't it not matter? Because the userdata is still there when i make a new request. Thus showing that CI can still match the user_agent... If it was the length of the field in the database that was the issue, then every server request, CI would insert a new row. Which isn't the case here. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: If it's any use it is: varchar(120). But I believe CI truncates it automatically to 120 anyways?